# Почему из функции недоступна глобальная переменная?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-faq

Подскажите пожалуйста почему функция не выводит в консоль значение s

```
s = "I'm global variable"

def foo():
    print(s)
    s = 'Reset global variable'

foo()
```

Я предполагал, что когда интерпретатор дойдёт до строки print(s), он поймёт, что в области видимости функции foo такой переменной не существует. Следовательно начнёт искать её во внешней области видимости, но там она есть.

Однако в результате в консоль выводится следующее сообщение об ошибке:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "index.py", line 7, in <module>
    foo()
  File "index.py", line 4, in foo
    print(s)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 's' referenced before assignment
```

Проблема исчезает, если закомментировать строку

```
s = 'Reset global variable'
```

но мне всё равно не понятен механизм

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Марк Лутц - "Изучаем Python", глава 20, страница 596

> Как известно, имена, которым выполняется присваивание внутри функции,
>   по умолчанию рассматриваются как локальные – они располагаются в
>   области видимости функции и существуют только во время работы функции.
>   Но я еще не говорил, что локальные переменные определяются статически,
>   во время компиляции программного кода в инструкции def, а не в
>   соответствии с операциями присваивания, производимыми во время
>   выполнения. Эта особенность становится причиной появления самых
>   причудливых сообщений в группе новостей, получаемых от начинающих
>   программистов. Обычно, если внутри функции имени не присваивается
>   какое-либо значение, поиск его будет производиться в области видимости
>   объемлющего модуля. Но посмотрите, что произойдет, если добавить
>   инструкцию присваивания переменной X после ее использования.
>
> ```
> X = 99
> >>> def selector():
> ... print(X) # Переменная еще не существует!
> ... X = 88 # X классифицируется как локальная переменная
> ... # То же самое происходит при “import X”, “def X”...
> >>> selector()
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> ...текст сообщения об ошибке опущен...
> UnboundLocalError: local variable ‘X’ referenced before assignment
> ```
>
> Было получено сообщение о том, что переменная не определена, но
>   причина его появления не очевидна. Этот программный код компилируется
>   интерпретатором во время ввода в интерактивной оболочке или во время
>   импорта модуля. Вовремя компиляции Python обнаруживает операцию
>   присваивания переменной X и делает вывод, что X – это локальное имя
>   везде в теле функции. Но во время выполнения функции, из-за того, что
>   к моменту вызова инструкции print операция присваивания еще не
>   производилась, интерпретатор сообщает о том, что имя не определено.
>   Согласно этому правилу использования имен, он говорит, что обращение к
>   локальной переменной X произведено до того, как ей было присвоено
>   значение. Фактически любая операция присваивания внутри функции
>   создает локальное имя. Операция импортирования, =, вложенные
>   инструкции def, вложенные определения классов и так далее – все
>   трактуются именно таким образом. Проблема возникает из-за того, что
>   операция присваивания делает имена локальными для всей функции, а не
>   только для той ее части, которая следует за инструкцией присваивания.

Читать учебники - полезно.

Answer (score 5):

В вашем коде не хватает объявления, что вы планируете использовать глобальную переменную локально с помощью директивы global.

```py
s = "I'm global variable"

def foo():
    global s  # here we go!
    print(s)
    s = 'Reset global variable'

foo()
```

Answer (score 0):

Операция присваивания делает имя `s` локальным для всей функции `foo`, а не только для ее части после присваивания. Это потому, что локальные переменные определяются во время компиляции, а не в соответствии с порядком операций использования и присваивания переменных во время выполнения функции.

Чтобы изменить глобальную переменную, передайте ее как аргумент в функцию и верните изменённое значение:

```
>>> s = "I'm global variable"
def foo(s):
...     print(s)
...     return 'Reset global variable'
...
>>> s = foo(s)
I'm global variable
>>> print(s)
Reset global variable
```