# Python функции и область видимости глобальных переменных

Tags: python, область-видимости

```
state = "1"
pstate = ""

def fst_start(bot, message):
    main_keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3, resize_keyboard=True)
    for txtbut in main_button_list:
        main_keyboard.add(types.KeyboardButton(text=txtbut))
    bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text=tostart, reply_markup=main_keyboard)
    pstate= state
    state = ' '
```

В этой функции в строке

```
pstate= state
```

питон ругается на state

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'state' referenced before assignment

Comment: И? Это проблема? В чем вопрос-то?

Comment: @Эникейщик В этом и вопрос. Почему `Python` не нашёл переменную, хотя она была объявлена в глобальной области видимости. Очень интересный вопрос.

Comment: Почему так, и как сделать, что бы в функции были видны эти глобальные переменные?

Comment: @Кирилл https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/982002/247581 -- в точности ответ на Ваш вопрос

Comment: Насколько я понял, нельзя использовать переменную, которой далее в функции присваивается значение, несмотря на то, что есть такая же в глобальной области видимости.

Comment: @nomnoms12, можно, если воспользоваться ключевым словом `global`.

Comment: @insolor Но тогда не удастся создать её потом локально. Речь идёт о том, чтобы использовать глобальное значение, а потом создать локальное имя и всё это в рамках одной функции. Если использовать `global`, то переменная будет глобальной навсегда. Автору не нужно перезаписывать глобальную переменную. По крайней мере, так я понял. Могу ошибаться, потому что автор так и не уточнил этот момент.

Comment: @nomnoms12, автору нужно записать текущее состояние и прошлое состояние в глобальную переменную. Вы придумали какое-то другое задание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как @Eurobeat_Intensifies [подсказал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/982002/247581) в комментариях, Вы не можете использовать переменную, которой далее в функции присваивается значение.

Но её всё ещё можно достать из словаря глобальной области видимости, что решает Вашу проблему.

***Пример:***

```py
x = 'hello'
y = 'spam'


def func():
    x = globals()['y']
    y = 'eggs'
    print(x, y)


func()
print(x, y)
```

***stdout:***

```html
spam eggs
hello spam
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы записать в глобальную переменную, нужно в функции указать, что она глобальная:

```
state = "1"
pstate = ""

def fst_start(bot, message):
    global state
    global pstate
    ...
    pstate= state
    state = ' '
```

Вообще, использование глобальных переменных не рекомендуется.