# В python выдаёт ошибку: local variable 'he' referenced before assignment ошибка

Tags: python

```
def convert():
    he=8
    p=2
    v=9
    d=1
    j=0
    def hisla():
        print("текст")
        he=(he-7)
    hisla()
    print(he)
convert()
```

Как можно исправить? Заранее спасибо:)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему из функции недоступна глобальная переменная?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/981999/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ключевое слово `nonlocal` используется для работы с переменными внутри вложенных функций, где переменная не должна принадлежать внутренней функции.

```
def convert():
    he=8
    p=2
    v=9
    d=1
    j=0

    def hisla():
        print("текст")
        nonlocal he
        he = (he - 7)

    hisla()
    print(he)

convert()
```

Comment: PS можно заменить на `he -= 7`

Answer (score 0):

Создавая вложенный метод внутри него создается локальная область видимости, и при попытке присвоить созданной переменной в методе уровнем выше иное значение таким образом:
`he = he - 7`
Компилятор пытается найти ее во вложенном методе, и соответственно не находит его. `nonlocal` "расширяет" область видимости, и за счет этого переменная становится доступна для манипуляций.